# Is my mergesort implementation with a comparator correct?

Tags: c++, vector, comparator, mergesort

I currently have a bruteforce function, a mergesort function that the client/user can access, another mergesort function not accessed by the client/user, and a merge function that is called in the mergesort. This is all located in my sort.h file

```
template <typename Comparable, typename Comparator>
void mergeSort(vector<Comparable> & a,
    vector<Comparable> & tmpArray, int left, int right, Comparator cmp)
{
    if (cmp(left,right))
    {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, tmpArray, left, center, cmp);
        mergeSort(a, tmpArray, center + 1, right, cmp);
        merge(a, tmpArray, left, center + 1, right,cmp);
    }
}

template <typename Comparable, typename Comparator>

void mergeSort2(vector<Comparable> & a, Comparator cmp)

{
    vector<Comparable> tmpArray(a.size());
    mergeSort(a, tmpArray, 0, a.size() - 1, cmp);

}


template <typename Comparable, typename Comparator>
void merge(vector<Comparable> & a, vector<Comparable> & tmpArray,
    int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd, Comparator cmp)
{
    int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
    int tmpPos = leftPos;
    int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;

    // Main loop
    while ((cmp(leftPos, leftEnd)) && (cmp(rightPos, rightEnd)))

        if (cmp(a[leftPos], a[rightPos]))
            tmpArray[tmpPos++] = std::move(a[leftPos++]);
        else
            tmpArray[tmpPos++] = std::move(a[rightPos++]);


    while (cmp(leftPos,leftEnd))    // Copy rest of first half
        tmpArray[tmpPos++] = std::move(a[leftPos++]);

    while (cmp(rightPos,rightEnd))  // Copy rest of right half
        tmpArray[tmpPos++] = std::move(a[rightPos++]);

    // Copy tmpArray back
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i, --rightEnd)
        a[rightEnd] = std::move(tmpArray[rightEnd]);
}
```

My two comparators are:

```
class CompareXCoordinate {
public:
    bool operator()(const Point & p1, const Point & p2) const
    {
        return (p1.getX() < p2.getX());
    }
};
class CompareYCoordinate {
public:
    bool operator()(const Point & p1, const Point & p2) const
    {
        return (p1.getY() < p2.getY());
    }
};
```

The output of the vector points before mergeSort2 is:

```
5.63585 0.0125126
8.08741 1.93304
4.79873 5.85009
8.95962 3.50291
7.46605 8.2284
8.58943 1.74108
5.13535 7.10501
```

Once I call the mergeSort2(points, Point::CompareXCoordinate());
The output is:

```
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Instead of being sorted by the X coordinate of points, it's just zero? Is this an issue with my merge function?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Any chance that your comparator yields `false` on the first comparison in `mergeSort` and thus the sorting never gets executed?

Comment: I don't think the main while loop is doing what you think it does. Might need to explicitly wrap the code in brackets.